# How do i create a schema for a geojson data in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I am working with mapbox api and I want to maintain a geojson data on my server itself so that i can fetch the data from this file to put pins on the map. if any one can tell me about the correct schema that has to be used for a geojson data then it would be really a great help for me.

Comment: What did you try? For starters, take a look at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere

Comment: If you are unsure of a schema to "start" with, then there is always `{ "strict" false }`. But I agree that this is easily addressed by looking at the general structure of GeoJSON objects. Which of course all examples are in **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation, if you ever wondered where the term came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple schema for one Point. and remember in mongo DB you have save [lon, lat]. in contrast to common pratice where latitude is mentioned first.

```
 {
            type       : {type: String, default: 'Point'},
            coordinates: {type: [Number]}
        }
```

Comment: i mean  coordinates should be saved like `coordinates :[longitude, latitude]`